# why fseek never return -1

Tags: c, linux, file, fseek

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and try to read binary file, but fseek never return -1 for out of file size.

Why this happend?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *fn = "myfile";
    FILE * fid;
    fid = fopen(fn, "r");
    int flag;
    while(1) {
        flag = fseek(fid, sizeof(float), SEEK_CUR);
        printf("flag: %d\n",flag);
        if(flag)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `sizeof float` important in your example? Anyway, it is valid to position the read cursor *beyond* the end of a file.

Comment: It is not important, how can i know I exceed the file with using the fseek..

Comment: You don't, as it is not something that `fseek` checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short reason: seeking to a position that exceeds the file size is not regarded as an error in `fseek`.

The following sections are quoted from `man 3 fseek`:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `rewind()` function returns no value.  Upon successful completion, `fgetpos()`, `fseek()`, `fsetpos()` return `0`, and `ftell()` returns the current offset.  Otherwise, `-1` is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> `EBADF`  The stream specified is not a seekable stream.
>   `EINVAL` The whence argument to `fseek()` was not `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_END`, or `SEEK_CUR`.  Or: the resulting file offset would be negative.

Which means:

```
// This is not an error
int ret_0 = fseek(file, 1, SEEK_END);
assert(ret_0 == 0);
// While this is an error
int ret_1 = fseek(file, -1, SEEK_SET);
assert(ret_1 == -1);
```

Comment: In second example ferror not set. Is there any difference between an error and unsuccessful execution?

Comment: @IvanIvanov In my test the 2nd example did set the `errno` to 22 which is `EINVAL`

Comment: Thank you, and how can i know I have been end of the file or exceed the end of the file in binary file..

Comment: @neouyghur `fstat` can be used to determine the size of file, or simply `fseek` to `SEEK_END` first, then read the return value of `ftell`

Comment: Also, attempting to read beyond an end-of-file returns `EOF`.

Comment: in that case the file pointer will change the position, does not it?

Comment: @neouyghur By "the file pointer" if you mean your `fid` pointer, then no. Or if you mean some member of `FILE` recording the offset, then yes.

Comment: @starrify when reach or beyond the file ftell value will bigger than eof, is that right? thank you.

Comment: @neouyghur Yes that's true, that `ftell` may return a value larger than the file size. You could also write some code to test yourself. :)

Comment: In the end I change the my code little bit, I use fread to check end of file. Because I am writing multi-thread function, so I have to use fseek to define the location. Thank you, you save my time. :))